# Servicebus Topic Message From signalR Hub to Specific Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, servicebus

We are trying to send Topic Message to distinguished connected clients who ever requested for that. A hub is hosted inside a WebRole with persistent connections.

The approach what implemented as of now is

---

1: Client has to Make a initial request to subscribe for a group, after this it won't make any call  for server method but it will wait for messages from server.

```
///Tenantid-fix KnownIDToClient
[HubMethodName("subscribe")]
public async Task Subscribe(string tenantid)
{
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantid))  
 await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, tenantid);
}
```

2: A Http Post Request to Initiate the onMessage Process for Subscription Client just after the subscribe Method Call.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "POST")]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetDeviceSettings([FromBody] string tenantid)
 {
   MessageReceiver.Instance.InitiateRequest(requestParms[0], tenantid);
 }
```

This Controller Method will initiate the OnMessage Request for Subscription Client

```
RtmSubsCriptionClient().OnMessage((msg) =>
{
 SendRtmTopicMessage(msg, tenantid);
 msg.CompleteAsync();
}
```

The Challenges here i am facing

1: i have to pass GroupName(tenantid) in onMessage to find the Client.

2: GC will dispose caller object for OnMessage Method as is originated from Controller Method and after response it doesn't have any scope of living object [Suspicion].

3: Multiple Post Method Call will trigger multiple OnMessage request,that Will Result in Exception ***OnMessage Method has been called on Message***.

One WorkAround , But don't Think this is going to work.

```
Task RealTimetask=new Task(async () => await   RecieveRealTimeBrokeredMessage(tenantid));

if (RealTimetask.IsCompleted)  RealTimetask.Start();
```

4: If i run OnMessage in background Thread , how can find to which client i have to send message as GroupName is not in scope here.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: I don't see completely how things hang together in your app, but I suspect you are having a scoping problem for the OnMessage loop. The callback is invoked for each message that is found and continues to run while the client is open. Before I can answer, a few questions: Who creates/holds the subscription client? Are the msgs in the sub for exactly one client?